# Update foreign key of Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, rest, api

I am making a small rest API app for the first time and I am completely stuck on 1
particular thing: Update my foreign key with a [HttpPost].

What do I mean with update?

Simple: consider the following easy application:
I want to make customers & make or assign a customer type to them (for instance "independent" or "private")

So I have the following classes:

```
public class Customer
{       
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }

    public Customer() { }
}
```

And

```
  public class CustomerType 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CustomerTypeName { get; set; }
    public CustomerType () { }
}
```

What can I do at this moment:
I have written my API so that I can create both a new customer and CustomerType  at
the same time!

```
[Route("NewCustomer")] 
    [HttpPost]
    public Customer NewCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        customerContext.Add(customer);
        customerContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

So I get a JSON body from somewhere that contains my customer name and CustomerType . Both ID's are 0 so entity framework saves it in the database and assigns an ID for both my new customer and the new CustomerType.

However: later on the private customers becomes an "Independant" customer. Now, this already exists in the database so there is no need to create a CustomerType "Independant".

The only thing I want to do, is change the customer's CustomerType Id from 1 to 2 (let's say 1 was Private and 2 is Independant).

When I post it to my API I send the following JSON via Postman:

```
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Test1",
  "CustomerType ": {
        "Id": "2"
    },
  }
```

When I say saveChanges it simply does not work, Entity framework does not recognize that it only needs to change the CustomerTypeId from 1 to 2 (once that is doesn, the customer is an Independant instead of a private).

The only way I can make it work at the moment , is that I first get CustomerType with Id 2 out of the database & "bind" it to my customer:(no need to look at the contexts etc, it's an example code)

```
[Route("NewCustomer")] 
    [HttpPost]
    public Customer NewCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
       CustomerType customerType=
      CustomerTypeContext.GetByID(customer.CustomerType.Id);
        customer.CustomerType = customerType;

        customerContext.Add(customer);
        customerContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

If I do the above it works just fine! Customer.CustomerType.Id went from 1 to 2 but why do I need to do this? Can't I say to Entity Framework: Hey, as you can see the Id went from 1 to 2 so can you please just change the ID & save it ? thanks EF.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to set the entity state of your child to modified. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx). "If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but to which changes may have been made then you can tell the context to attach the entity and set its state to Modified."

Comment: You don't show the update action method.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a 1:n relation in entity framework add the following to your code ([learn more](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)):

```
public class Customer
{  


[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
public int CustomerTypeId {get; set;}

public Customer() { }


}


  public class CustomerType 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Customer> Customers {get; set}
    public string CustomerTypeName { get; set; }

    public CustomerType () { }
}
```

If there can be customers without a customer type, just make the CustomerTypeId nullable `int? CustomerTypeId`

If you are using fluent api you can write:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configures one-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerType>()
            .HasRequired<Customer>(c => c.CustomerTypeId)
            .WithMany(ct => ct.Customers)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(c => c.CustomerTypeId);          }
    }
```

Don't forget to add a new migration after doing the code changes and to update your database, e. g. with the packet manager.
Now entity framework knows about the relationship between Customer and CustomerType.

Comment: But doesn't EF already know about CustomerType in Customer since... well.. it is defined in Customer and has a column in the table dbo.Customer? EDIT: so by adding CustomerTypeId, I have 2x columns about the CustomerType in table Customer? Never heard of that.

Comment: No ef only adds the CustomerTypeId field to the dbo.Customer table. This is the foreign key. the CustomerType property in the Customer entity stands for the customerType object that is related to the customer object and does not result into a database field

Comment: Alright! I will have to change a shit ton of classes if this is the fix! I will try it & get back to you!

Comment: You do not need to explicitly add the FK. Working with just navigation properties is fine. EF will a field like CustomerType_ID automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: @Steve Greene then do you know why the API update does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found it.

According to EF I need to use Update instead of Add.

```
public virtual void UpdateZonderAttach(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        context.Update<TEntity>(entityToUpdate);
    }
```

Because of Update instead of Add, EF will look for each entity if it already has an ID or not, of not it adds it & if it does, it updates which is sort of fine for me I guess, could have been better to just "link" it instead of totally updating the CustomerType